# kendoui: Displaying foreign key value not ID

Tags: listview, foreign-keys, kendo-ui

I have a kendo ui listView and in edit mode im using dropdownlist to handle my foreign keys, these work fine in displaying the foreign key value and not the ID, however in normal view mode which loads up first the foreign key ID is displayed instead of the value.

Im just wondering what the best practice is when wanting to display the foreign key value. Ive tried solving the problem at SQL level by using the 'INNER JOIN' statement in the datasource read call, but this then causes fields conflicts when doing and update/create as the foreign key value field doesnt exist in the original table.

heres my code for the lenders dropdown

```
var dsLenders = new kendo.data.DataSource({
transport: {
read: {
          url: "../data/lenders/",
          dataType: "jsonp"
      },
      parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
          if (operation === "read") {
              return options;
          }
      }
    }
});
```

Heres the code for the list view

```
var claimListView = $("#formClaim").kendoListView({
      dataSource: remoteDataSource,
      template: kendo.template($("#viewTemplate").html()),
      editTemplate: kendo.template($("#formTemplate").html()),
      dataBound: function(e) {
          this.edit(this.element.children().first());
     }
  }).data("kendoListView");
```

heres my dropdownlist in the editTemplate which loads list of Lenders which works fine

```
<input name="idldr_clm" data-bind="value:idldr_clm" data-value-field="id_ldr" data-text-field="name_ldr" data-option-label="Select" data-source="dsLenders" data-role="dropdownlist" />
```

now here what im using in the normal view template view to display the lender. but its showing the ID and not the lender name. i want it to pull the lenders name.

```
<input value="#= idldr_clm #" class="k-input k-textbox" readonly />
```

Comment: No way following an unknown link.  Post some code.  Your problem is probably easily solved here.

Comment: Thanks. I just thought showing you would be best as its difficult to explain. Am on my ipad at present so havent got the code to hand but will post later. I basically have a kendoui list view which loads up client information and on the edit template form I have a drop down which is sourced from a remote list of lenders. So my problem is when the list view is not in edit mode it just shows the lenders ID value and not the lenders name. This I's because the drop down only appears in edit mode. So how can I replace the I'd with the lenders actual name.

Comment: Will post code later after I finish work

Comment: ive added the code to the original post.

Comment: Where did you get the example you are working off?

Comment: I took the example from kendoui listview example an modified it. ive been using grids to display clients and wanted to be able to click on the client in the list amd it load a details page with a form to edit the clients claim information. However i couldnt find a simple kendo example for binding a remote datasource to a simple form. So what i did was you the listView and simply limited it to 1 record. But now im having trouble because i cant display the dropdown in the normal view only in edit mode. so the lenders (foreign key) displays the id and not the lenders name.

Comment: ive added the dropdown list datasource code above if that helps